# Solidity: Reading events with web3.eth.contract

Tags: web3js, events

I am trying to read events issued on my hardhat local node.

My code is the following

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonFile = "artifacts/contracts/STPOAP_ERC.sol/STPOAP_ERC.json";
var parsed= JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonFile));
var abi = parsed.abi;
//console.log(abi)

const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
//var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');

var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3', {
  from: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3', // default from address: the same as the smartcontract address?
  gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
});

 

async function main() {
  
    console.log(await myContract.events.tokenReceived({
      filter: {test: "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
      fromBlock: 0
  }, function(error, event){ console.log(event); }))
  .on('data', function(event){
      console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
  })
  .on('changed', function(event){
      // remove event from local database
  })
  .on('error', console.error);
  
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

When I execute the function, I receive the following error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Trying to debug this since many hours. does someone see the mistake?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

I think you might be mixing up event logs with the events emitted by web3.js when sending a transaction, like in this case, deploying a smart contract.

> Please correct me if my assumption is wrong here!

It looks like you need to listen to events emitted by a smart contract, but the `Contract.events.` method in this case, is to catch events emitted by the transaction itself.

You can find the source code in [Web3.js contracts.ts file](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/f1c69161aecb9602c46e11fe2faee22d52352d0c/packages/web3-eth-contract/src/contract.ts#L590). As you can see here, the events emitted are:

```js
     sendObject.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
       ...
     });
     sendObject.on('receipt', function(receipt){
       ...
     });
     sendObject.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
       ...
     });
     sendObject.on('error', function(error, receipt) {
       ...
     });
```

This means that you can extract this kind of data, for example, get the transaction hash immediately after the transaction is sent with `sendObject.on('transactionHash', function(hash)`, or wait for the receipt  or the confirmation.

If you want to listen for event emitted by a smart contract, you have a couple of options:

#### Real-time events

To listen for events in real time, you can use a WSS endpoint and subscriptions. Here is an example to listen for `Transfer` events on the `WETH` contract.

```js
const { Web3 } = require("web3");

const NODE_URL =
  "YOUR_WSS_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

// Only log transfer events from the WETH smart contract.
const logsFilter = {
  address: "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2", // Contract address
  topics: [
    "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", // Event signature
  ],
};

async function subscribeToLogs() {
  try {
    // Create a new subscription to the 'logs' event with the specified filter
    const subscription = await web3.eth.subscribe("logs", logsFilter);
    console.log(`Subscription ID: ${subscription.id}`);
    // Attach event listeners to the subscription object
    subscription.on("data", handleLogs);
    subscription.on("error", handleError);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error subscribing to new logs: ${error}`);
  }
}

// Fallback functions to react to the different events

// Event listener that logs the filtered events
function handleLogs(log) {
  console.log("Received log:", log);
}

// Event listener that logs any errors that occur
function handleError(error) {
  console.error(`Error with log subscription: ${error}`);
}

subscribeToLogs();
```

You have a couple options to get the event signature:

- Use this tool I made - [The EVM
  Swiss Army Knife](https://web3tools.chainstacklabs.com/generate-event-signature)
- Generate the signature programmatically:

```js
function encodeEvent(event) {
  const keccakHash = Web3.utils.keccak256Wrapper(event);
  return keccakHash;
}

const eventToEncode = "Transfer(address,address,uint256)";
const signature = encodeEvent(eventToEncode);
console.log(signature);
```

#### Past events

If you want to fetch past events, then you can use the [`getPastEvents` method](https://docs.web3js.org/libdocs/Contract#getpastevents), which looks like you are trying to use in this case.

This example gets the past `Tranfer` events of `WETH` to this specific address `0xBa0E5766E74A3dCa446Fd4a7724808b468BBB176`.

This is how the event looks like in the `WETH` contract:

```
event  Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint wad);
```

So, in this case we fitler for the `dst` parameter.

```js
async function main() {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    abi,
    "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"
  );

  const events = await contract.getPastEvents("Transfer", {
    filter: {
      //src: ["0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"],
      dst: ["0xBa0E5766E74A3dCa446Fd4a7724808b468BBB176"],
    },
    fromBlock: 18763643n,
    toBlock: "latest",
  });

  console.log(events);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Based on your code snippet, you could do it like this

```js
  const events = await contract.getPastEvents("tokenReceived", {
    filter: {
      test: ["0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"],
    },
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: "latest",
  });

  console.log(events);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Note that where it has `test` you need to add the indexed event parameter you are looking for, unless the parameter is named `test`.

You can learn more about listening to real-time events here:

- [ethereum-subscribelogs](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-subscribelogs)
- [handle-real-time-data-using-websockets-with-javascript-and-python](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/handle-real-time-data-using-websockets-with-javascript-and-python)

> Please note that those examples are using `web3js@1.10.0`, I'm working on updating the code examples to the new version 4!

Feel free to reach out if you need help.

Comment: Thank you Sir! It works perfectly. I really appreciate your help! You saved my day!

Comment: Awsome, Anytime ser!